# How to call fancybox resize function when fancybox-wrap height changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have need to show this gallery as http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ResponsiveImageGallery/  in fancy box.  It works fine except one design problem that is fancybox doesn't come in the center for first time as it has to download few image for first time if one open the same album second time it then show correctly in the center as all image are cached. I tried to resolve this issue with following code but it is not work

I cant give fancybox fixed width and height as images are of different dimensions

```
$(".fancybox-frame").fancybox({
    maxWidth: 740,
    maxHeight: 600,
    fitToView: false,
    width: '70%',
    height: '70%',
    autoSize: true,
    closeClick: true,
    hideOnOverlayClick: true,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    onComplete: function () {
        $.fancybox.resize();
        $.fancybox.center();
    }
});
```

Other solution i can think of is to call `fancybox.center()` and `$.fancybox.center();` function  when fancybox wrapper with changes `fancybox-wrap`.

This i can help me correctly repositioning the fancybox in center.

But i am not sure how to track  height change for `fancybox-wrap` and call the reposition the fancy box.

Fancybox V 1.3.4
Help in this regarding is appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

Just to give you an idea i face similar problem that is happend on this link.

http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/getImageAjax.html

When you click for the first time it small fancy-box and doesn't re-size when image is downloaded. In my case i have to download multiple image and it take time to display the first image in between takes default value but doent resize when first image is download.

Comment: I would like to think that you are using fancybox v2.x, aren't you? If so, neither `onComplete`, `$.fancybox.resize()` or `$.fancybox.center()` are valid options or methods (those are for v1.3.4 and not compatible with v2.x). Use `afterShow`, `$.fancybox.update()` and `$.fancybox.reposition()` instead. Check the proper documentation http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs

Comment: Then `maxWidth`, `maxHeight`, `fitToView`, `autoSize`, `closeClick`, `openEffect` and `closeEffect` are NOT valid options for v1.3.4. Check the proper documentation http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: @JKF, but my main issue is still their.

Comment: @Anilkumar, is fancybox 2 free for commercial use...

Comment: @Anilkumar, It say it is not free for commercial use `fancyBox licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 license.
You are free to use fancyBox for your personal or non-profit website projects.
You can get the author's permission to use fancyBox for commercial websites by paying a fee. `

Comment: @Anilkumar : make sure you check the facts before commenting http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license fancybox 2 is not free for commercial use and it can be one of the reasons people may don't want to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

set `autoSize` to false in order to set width and height for fancybox. i.e.

```
$(".fancybox-frame").fancybox({
    maxWidth: 740,
    maxHeight: 600,
    fitToView: false,
    autoSize: false,
    width: '70%',
    height: '70%',
    closeClick: true,
    hideOnOverlayClick: true,
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
    onComplete: function () {
        $.fancybox.resize();
        $.fancybox.center();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Anil, this is the problem nothing seems to work and for this reason i want to track changes in div `fancybox-wrap` and then reposition fancybox.

Comment: In order to set width and height for fancybox we've to set autoSize to false, try to use `$.fancybox.update` instead of `$.fancybox.resize();`

Comment: Anil, It crash by fancybox.close event.

Comment: do you want to change the height while sliding images?

Comment: Height automatically changes based on the image.. or when first image download completely

Comment: what's the problem i'm not understanding :(

Answer (score 2):

**Dynamic Inline Content Loading**

```
  function loadAnswer(id){    
    jQuery.fancybox({       
      'content' : jQuery("#outerFAQ"+id).html(),        
       /*For Auto height and width*/
       'onComplete' : function(){
          jQuery('#fancybox-wrap').css({height:'auto',width:'auto'});
          jQuery.fancybox.resize();
          jQuery.fancybox.center(); 
        }
      }); 
    }

/*Dynamically Set the id and passing it to function*/  
 <a class="fancybox"  href="#" onClick="loadAnswer(<?php echo $data->getId()/*Dynamic id*/ ?>);"> Demo </a>

    <div id="outerFAQ<?php echo $data->getId(); ?>"  style="display:none;"> 
      <div id="ans<?php echo $data->getId();?>">
        demo        
      </div>
    <div>
```

**Single inline content loading**

```
   jQuery( "#demo" ).click(function() {
      jQuery.fancybox({
        'content' : jQuery("#demoContent").html(),
        onComplete: function () {
        /*Static height width*/  
        jQuery("#fancybox-content").css({
          height:'500px',
          overflow:'scroll',
        });
        jQuery("#fancybox-wrap").css("top","10");
        jQuery(".fancybox-wrap").css("position", "absolute");
      }
    });

    <a  id="demo"  href="#">Click me</a>

    <div style="display: none">
      <div id="demoContent">
        demo
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you fancybox is already open and want to resize then below code will helps you.

```
      $.ajax({
                url: 'YOUR URL',
                data:'DATA WANT TO TRANSFER',
                type: 'post'
                dataType: "text",
                success:function(result){                       
                    //PLAY WITH RESULT SET

                    $.fancybox.toggle();

                },
                error:function(request,error){
                    alert("Error occured : "+error);

                }
            });
```

Reference from : [Resize Fancybox](http://www.jaiswar-vipin-r.com/resize-fancybox/)

Answer (score 0):

Solution, I managed to make it work by resizing  after delay of 3 seconds by that time first image is downloaded completely

```
    $(".fancybox-iframe").fancybox({
        width: '70%',
        height: '70%',
        hideOnOverlayClick: true,
        centerOnScroll:true,
        onComplete : function(){
            // $.fancybox.resize();
            // $.fancybox.center();
             var resize = setTimeout(function () {
                 $.fancybox.center();
             }, 3000)
             }
    });
```

I believe more professional approach will be check using jquery when image is downloaded completely and then call `$.fancybox.center();` function

Please if this is fine or we can do it some otherway.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use `<center></center>` include of your fancybox? I think so it'll work on your page. and no need to use java, cause you are just trying to use it as center.

Comment: I don't think the OP is using java at all.